# storage\logs/laravel.log" could not be opened in append mode: failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: php, laravel-8, plesk, permission-denied, windows-server

I have developed my application in Laravel 8, it's working fine in localhost and Linux server.
But When I deployed it in Plesk Windows Server it's showing permission denied error.

*UnexpectedValueException
The stream or file "C:\inetpub\vhosts\rcns.edu.pk\Admission.rcns.edu.pk\storage\logs/laravel.log" could not be opened in append mode: failed to open stream: Permission denied*

I cannot run such commands in SSH because my sever PLesk is windows server.

What should I do now?

Comment: Go to permission tab in folder properties and give access to Everyone and try it

Answer (score 27):

Use this command it's works in my case

```
sudo chmod -R ugo+rw storage
```

the solution from:
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-the-stream-or-file-storagelogslaravellog-could-not-be-opened-in-append-mode-failed-to-open-stream-permission-denied?page=1&replyId=724250

Comment: this not for windows !

Comment: this worked for me on centos 8. but can you explain what "ugo+rw" does?

Comment: works perfectly on macOs

Comment: This is 777 and risky

Answer (score -1):

I have solved this problem by deleting this file

```
storage/logs/laravel.log
```

After deleting this file I have run the command

```
php artisan optimize:clear
```

-> this command will remove all cache those have on your system